# How to change ResourceServerConfiguration order

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

When put on `@EnableResourceServer`, [enabled `ResourceServerConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.6.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.java#L46).

Although default order of `ResourceServerConfiguration` is[`3`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.6.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfiguration.java#L49), I want to change it lower.

How to change it?

Comment: Have you tried with @Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

---

I've missed [following description](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.3.6.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.java#L36-L38)...:

> The annotation creates a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a hard-coded Order (of 3). It's not possible to change the order right now owing to technical limitations in Spring, so you must avoid using order=3 in other WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters in your application (Spring Security will let you know if you forget).